# bind view clause causes fail

Tags: ubuntu, bind, rndc

I'm trying to setup views in my bind9 configuration. I use ubuntu 10.04.
When I add

```
view "general" {
   match-clients { any; };
};
```

I try to reload bind9 and rndc but it fails.

```
rndc: 'reload' failed: failure
```

Does any one know how to solve this ? Or where I can find the logs?

Andrew

Comment: Check your log files and/or `named-checkconf -zj` output and include this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the log files for details. By default, BIND logs into /var/log/syslog.

The most frequent error people have with views is that once you start using views, all of your zones must be in a view, which includes all your default zones (these are configured through /etc/bind/named.conf. /etc/bind/named.conf.local and /etc/bind/zones.rfc1918). You cannot have any zones outside of a view. However, without analysis of the log files, this is only a blind guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors should be in /var/log/daemon.log. Comment out the include for /etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones in /etc/named/named.conf

I have the zones defintions for my public zones in /etc/bind9/named.conf.zones. My external view (included in /etc/named/named.conf.local looks like:

```
view "external-in" in {
        // Our external (untrusted) view. We permit any client to access
        // portions of this view. We do not perform recursion or cache
        // access for hosts using this view.

        match-clients { any; };
        allow-query { none; };          // Secure queries
        allow-query-cache { none; };            // Secure cache
        recursion no;
        additional-from-auth yes;
        additional-from-cache yes;

        zone "." {
                type hint;
                file "/etc/bind/db.root";
        };

        include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zones";
};
```